# How do I execute Javascript only after a deferred Javascript external file has loaded?

Tags: javascript, resources, external, onload

I want to defer loading of an external Javascript file until the page has loaded (and also I don’t want to block rendering if those external resources cannot be loaded).  So I have this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=“//external.otherdomain.com/path/js/myresoures.js" defer></script>
```

However, when this file does eventually load, I want to run the following …

```
<script type="text/javascript">_satellite.pageBottom();</script>
```

However, as is, the above may run before the script has loaded.  How do I run the above (or any) Javascript only after a remote resource has loaded?  Keep in mind that if the external resource doesn’t load (it times out, for example), I don’t want to run the Javascript.

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by an onload function.

You can dynamically load each... This example is pulled right from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement). It will insert your external resource above the script you call `importScript()` then launch the callback after loading.

`sSrc` = your external script, `fOnload` = the callback

```
function importScript (sSrc, fOnload) {
  var oScript = document.createElement("script");
  oScript.type = "text\/javascript";
  oScript.defer = true;
  if (fOnload) { oScript.onload = fOnload; }
      document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(oScript, document.currentScript);
  oScript.src = sSrc;
}
```

Usage:

```
importScript("//external.otherdomain.com/path/js/myresoures.js", function () { _satellite.pageBottom(); });
```

Or if jQuery is an option, use [.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) like so:

```
$.getScript( "//external.otherdomain.com/path/js/myresoures.js", function () {_satellite.pageBottom();} );
```

Either of these options can be used in a `<script>` at the end of the page, after *the fold* as they say, ensuring the entire DOM loads first.

Comment: jQuery's getScript does not load the resource as deferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `$(window).load();`

see: http://api.jquery.com/load/